# Spark unit testing not working with powermockito

Tags: unit-testing, apache-spark, powermock, rdd

I am writing unit tests for my spark application. I used powermockito to test a transformation. 
When I run the junit test I got error like,

```
2016-03-24 17:10:10:805 INFO  - Running Spark version 1.6.0
2016-03-24 17:10:11:479 WARN  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-03-24 17:10:11:586 ERROR - Can't find user in Subject:
    Principal: NTUserPrincipal: My_userNAME
    Principal: NTSidUserPrincipal: S-1-5-21-1082354718-1040695487-3441060932-16865
    Principal: NTDomainPrincipal: MY_DOMAIN
    .............
    ...........
    Public Credential: NTNumericCredential: 1872
```

When I remove the udage of powermockito the above error is gone. I don't know why powermockito is not working on spark rdd transformation.

Comment: could you paste the sample code?

Answer (score 4):

I was also experiencing the same problem. I found the solution, The main problem was with PowerMockRunner and spark session. This is can be rectified by adding

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.apache.hadoop.*","javax.*","com.sun.org.apache.*"})
```

It worked for me. Still If you face some error , try to figure out what internal classes are being called, and finally ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

@PowerMockIgnore() works with the following dependency being added to my build.gradle file

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.holdenkarau/spark-testing-base
testImplementation group: 'com.holdenkarau', name: 'spark-testing-base_2.11', version: '2.1.0_0.7.4'